# How to resolve "Unable to resolve host" in OpenStack Yoga?

Tags: centos, openstack

I’m trying to install Openstack on CentOS Stream 9 by following the official openstack installation guide for Yoga available at: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/

1. When I try to bootstrap keystone I get the following error: `/etc/keystone/fernet-keys/` does not exist.

[image: keystone error]

2. When I tried to create a domain using `openstack domain create --description "An Example Domain" example` it failed. Upon pinging controller I found out that the machine could not resolve the controller. Next, I added an entry to `/etc/hosts` that explicitly resolved the controller to my machine’s IP

[image: controller error]

3. Pinging the controller succeeded but I was still not able to create a domain
4. I tried creating a project using `openstack project create --domain default --description "Service Project" service` This command failed with internal server error.

[image: internal server error]

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: Please don't paste pictures but add the actual terminal output. You can't create any resources if keystone is not running, and keystone is not running because the bootstrap failed. You can create the directory `/etc/keystone/fernet-keys/` yourself (set keystone as the owner) and retry. It might be a bug that this directory is not created during package installation so consider checking https://bugs.launchpad.net/ for existing bugs and/or create a new one for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

please provide more details about commands you run before creating domain (did you successfully sync the database ?) .

based on info you gave you didn't run

```
keystone-manage credential_setup --keystone-user keystone --keystone-group keystone
```

how ever if you already did that